# How do I create a modal when I click TouchableOpacity in React Native?

Tags: react-native

```
 <TouchableOpacity>
     <Text style={styles1.picturebutton}>Picture</Text>
 </TouchableOpacity>
```

When I click "Picture", I want to get a modal(popup). How can I do so?

Thank you so much

Comment: You can check it in the documentation. https://reactnative.dev/docs/modal

Comment: Trust me I read that over and over gain and tried but it didnt work at all

Comment: have you tried the example they have given in documentation? You can share you whole code so one can check where the things are going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You can do with something like this:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import { View, Modal, TouchableOpacity, Text} from 'react-native'

export default class ViewPager extends Component {

  constructor(props: Props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      IsModalVisible: false
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Modal visible={this.state.IsModalVisible} onRequestClose={() => this.setState({IsModalVisibl: false})}>
          <View>
            <Text style={{color: (IsDarkThemeActive[0] ? 'white' : 'black')}}>Your modal Here</Text>
          </View>
        </Modal>
       <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.setState({IsModalVisible: true})}>
           <Text style={styles1.picturebutton}>Picture</Text>
       </TouchableOpacity>
     </View>
    )
  }
}
```

A button who changes the state of the visibility of the modal

Comment: Can I message you for details? Thank you

Comment: Or could you message me?

Comment: Comment your questions here so others can help you too

Comment: Well, add it to the question so. But i don't think anyone would read, if it's too long. So make sure to try the code i made on my answer. If it helped, make sure to mark as accepted answer. Thanks in advance

Answer (score -1):

You should take a look at : https://reactnative.dev/docs/modal its not that hard to accomplish.

Basically you set a state like showModal and say it is false by default but when you click your button it turns true and if u click it again it toggles back.

Then you just have to conditinally tell react native where it should render the modal if showModal is set to true.

Gl Faded.